# NFC using foregroundDispatch in react-native and android

Tags: react-native, nfc

I'm trying to develop an app in react-native that should use android's [foreground dispatch system](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc.html#foreground-dispatch) to intercept nfc events before any other activity does.
The android part is not a problem, I have done it in a native app.

What would the correct way of doing this be in an app that uses react-native?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up adding creation of pending intent and adding of tag/NDEF filters to `MainActivity`. Then `onNewIntent` parses the relevant data and relays it to js via

```
getReactInstanceManager()
  .getCurrentReactContext()
  .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
  .emit("nfcTagEvent", params);
```

Then, in my main RN component

```
DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('nfcTagEvent', event =>
  // do something with event
);
```